# Remotely power on PowerEdge 2900

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

Is there a way to remotely power on a PowerEdge 2900. I can ping the ip address that the BMC was set to, but I don't know how to access it. I've used ports 80, 443, and 1311. What port should I be using? Can I telnet in or just http? Once in, is there an option for power on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should use port 623.  However, you can use the IPMI shell.  There are versions for both Windows and Linux.  See [the IPMI docs](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smbmcmu/1.2/en/ug/bmcugc0d.htm#1067804).  Once you're logged on, I think you want the `power on` command.

Comment: 623...not working either :-(

Comment: @Jason, did you try installing BMC Management Utility client program?  The page I linked says it should be on a CD.

Comment: IPMI. Just was I needed. It's also available from the driver download page in the OpenManage Management Station package. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a DRAC interface card. Do you have that?
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_DRAC